# Using React.lazy vs. webpack dynamic imports?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I was wondering what the difference is between "declaring" dynamic imports using `React.lazy()` like:

```
const Component = React.lazy(() => import('./Component'));
```

Or doing it using webpack's dynamic imports like explained here:
https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports

(In my case, i'm planning on doing the bundling in webpack anyway)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`React.lazy` gets a callback which returns a Promise, and **returns** a renderable component.

Webpacks dynamic imports returns a Promise which will be resolved when the chunk is loaded, therefore, you can't directly render it.

You can reimplement what `React.lazy` does, this is really basic implementation.

```js
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {LazyComponent: null};

  async componentDidMount() {
    const LazyComponent = await import('./path/to/LazyComponent');
    this.setState({LazyComponent});
  }
  render() {
    const {LazyComponent} = this.state;
    return LazyComponent ? <LazyComponent {...props} /> : null;
  }
}
```

Comment: So just to make sure i understand - i can't use Webpack dynamic imports for components? Only for third party libraries, since nothing that comes out of those dynamic imports is renderable?

Comment: Correct, You cannot render a promise,